# Parse bibtex from url

Tags: parsing, beautifulsoup, bibtex, pyhook

I need to parse bibtex file in python referred by an url for eg: " https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/papers/J/J18/J18-1001.bib"
From bibtex I need to extract "pages" field. How to achieve this in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read it in as a string, then regex to get the string following pages:

```
import requests
import re

url = 'https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/papers/J/J18/J18-1001.bib'
data = requests.get(url).text

print (re.search(r'(?<=pages = \").*?(?=\",)', data).group())
```

**Output:**

```
'1--15'
```

Comment: @sayakchowdhury, be sure to accept the solution then